# Why are some characters more preferred in some areas?

Tags: character-variant

Why are some characters preferred in some areas more than others? I am referring to 綫 vs 線 in Hong Kong. They mean the same thing right?

I was also reading some articles related to the Dragon Boat Festival, why is 粽 preferred, but I also see the character 糭 in some (but really rare occasions).

Would you have other examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traditional 綫 vs. 線?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/38766/traditional-%e7%b6%ab-vs-%e7%b7%9a)

Comment: No. They are not the same, 綫 means boundary line as 前綫, 界綫, whereas 線 is the tangible thread, string line, 縫衣線, 毛線, 情牽一線. Your question is too broad, as there are regional differences, as well as differences between traditional and simplified Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

This is called 异体字 and I don't know this concept in English. In the old days, there are often multiple characters for a single 字, if you know some japanese kanji, you would even find more 异体字, some even different from those in China.

Comment: Corresponding English concept should be [spellings](https://www.oxfordinternationalenglish.com/differences-in-british-and-american-spelling/), e.g. favor v.s. favour, analyse v.s. analyze, and travelled v.s. traveled. The connection to kanji is fantastic!

Comment: Right! It is indeed an analogy!